# Weight variable in dplyr top_n

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to use the `top_n` function in package `dplyr`, but it only appears to be working when I let the function use the default weight (the last variable in the dataframe). The following example (using the default weight) works:

```
library(babynames)
ba <- babynames
ba %>% filter(year == 2013) %>% group_by(sex) %>% top_n(n = 5)

Selecting by prop
Source: local data frame [10 x 5]
```

However, these do not:

```
ba %>% filter(year == 2013) %>% group_by(sex) %>% top_n(n = 5, wt = "prop")
Source: local data frame [33,072 x 5]

ba %>% filter(year == 2013) %>% group_by(sex) %>% top_n(n = 5, wt = prop)
Error in top_n(`ba %>% filter(year == 2013) %>% group_by(sex)`, n = 5,  : 
  object 'prop' not found
```

Comment: This seems to be an [**open issue on the `dplyr` github**](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/426)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug. Please file a bug-report. Here's a corrected version that seems to work as expected.

```
top_n <- function (x, n, wt = NULL) 
{
  wt <- substitute(wt) # new line to correct is.null(wt)
  if (is.null(wt)) {
    vars <- tbl_vars(x)
    message("Selecting by ", vars[length(vars)])
    wt <- as.name(vars[length(vars)])
  }
  call <- substitute(filter(x, rank(desc(wt), ties.method = "min") <= 
                              n), list(n = n, wt = substitute(wt)))
  eval(call)
}
```